# Changing a pointer as a result of destroying an "object" in C

Tags: c, pointers, null

As part of a course I am attending at the moment, we are working in C with self-developed low level libraries, and we are now working in our final project, which is a game.

At a certain point, it seemed relevant to have a struct (serving as a sort of object) that held some important information about the current game status, namely a pointer to a player "object" (can't really call the simulated objects we are using actual objects, can we?).

It would go something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    //Holds relevant information about game current state
    state_st currstate;
    //Buffer of events to process ('array of events')
    //Needs to be pointers because of deallocating memory
    event_st ** event_buffer;
    //Indicates the size of the event buffer array above
    unsigned int n_events_to_process;
    //... Other members ...
    //Pointer to a player (Pointer to allow allocation and deallocation)
    Player * player;
    //Flag that indicates if a player has been created
    bool player_created;
} Game_Info;
```

The problem is the following:

If we are to stick to the design philosophy that is used in most of this course, we are to "abstract" these "objects" using functions like `Game_Info * create_game_info()` and `destroy_game_info(Game_Info * gi_ptr)` to act as constructors and destructors for these "objects" (also, "member functions" would be something like `update_game_state(Game_Info * gi_ptr)`, acting like C++ by passing the normally implicit `this` as the first argument).

Therefore, as a way of detecting if the player object inside a Game_Info "instance" had already been deleted I am comparing the player pointer to NULL, since in all of the "destructors", after deallocating the memory I set the passed pointer to NULL, to show that the object was successfully deallocated.

This obviously causes a problem (which I did not detect at first, and thus the player_created bool flag that fixed it while I still was getting a grasp on what was happening) which is that because the pointer is passed by copy and not by reference, it is not set to NULL after the call to the "object" "destructor", and thus comparing it to NULL is not a reliable way to know if the pointer was deallocated.

I am writing this, then, to ask for input on what would be the best way to overcome this problem:

- A flag to indicate if an "object" is "instanced" or not - using the flag instead of `ptr == NULL` in comparisons to assert if the "object" is "instanced" - the solution I am currently using
- Passing a pointer to the pointer (calling the functions with `&player` instead of only `player`) - would enable setting to NULL
- Setting the pointer to NULL one "level" above, after calling the "destructor"
- Any other solution, since I am not very experienced in C and am probably overlooking an easier way to solve this problem.

Thank you for reading and for any advice you might be able to provide!

Comment: *"can't really call the simulated objects we are using actual objects, can we?"* - The C standard does, so I don't see why you can't.

Comment: Checking if the pointer is NULL is the correct way of doing this, which will work once you make sure you're deallocating the memory in your "deconstructor". Do not find a way around ACTUALLY deallocating the memory. Doing this will work of course, but you create a memory leak in the process and getting in the habit of creating memory leaks is a no-no.

Comment: No need to be coy about "object", "instance", etc. If you are programming using object-oriented methods, then that's OOP, even if the language you're using has no explicit support for it.

Comment: After re-reading I also see "Passing a pointer to the pointer (calling the functions with &player instead of only player) - would enable setting to NULL" and I am hoping you mean by freeing that memory.. not just by setting the value to "NULL".

Comment: @CoreyLakey The problem is that I am in fact freeing the memory, and doing something like `free(player_ptr); player_ptr = NULL;`
However, player_ptr is never set to NULL since because the pointer is passed as a function argument, it is passed by copy, and thus it is not possible to change the value of the pointer itself with consequences on the "outside scope" of the function. That is what I am referencing as a problem, because after calling the player destructor somewhere, I cannot simply do if(p_ptr != NULL) to know if it is currently allocated or not :/

Comment: Wait.. are you trying to deconstruct the whole struct or just the member?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Sorry about that, was not sure if I could call them objects, constructors and whatnot after hearing for so long that C was explicitly a non-object-oriented language, I guess

Comment: @CoreyLakey Just the member, which gets constructed and deconstructed several times in the lifetime of the Game_Info object in my implementation, thus the need to check if it is NULL
I will also construct and deconstruct the whole struct but that is working fine (except it probably will have the same problem if I try to use it elsewhere... which is also a good reason to refactor the code according to this question I guess)

Comment: @Meiogordo Why deconstruct just the member? Do you only have 1 player?

Comment: @CoreyLakey I want to construct and deconstruct the player on entering different levels of the game.
Regardless of that, the question here is a different one, it is how to deal with setting an object implemented like this to "completely deconstructed", as in, also setting the passed pointer to NULL to indicate that the object was truly deconstructed or using a flag to show that, or another solution, that is the actual question here, if we are to stay on topic...

Comment: Because the same problem would apply to the Game_Info struct, it could be deconstructed and then if we checked if the pointer to it was NULL, it would not be, since the deconstructors receive the pointer by value, thus not enabling setting the pointer to NULL. Thus, the question is larger than just this specific case with the player

Comment: @Meiogordo It all seems relevant but anyways... If you are passing a player to a function without passing by reference you will never actually deconstruct. It needs to be passed the actual pointer to where that player was originally constructed (malloced) otherwise it is just a new temporarily created "player" and will disappear and have no affect on your "player" after the function returns. It does not matter what you do to that player in your function, it will have no side-effect on your player you allocated memory for.

Comment: @Meiogordo If my last reply doesn't make sense, maybe show some code of what you're trying to do. Like where the player is allocated, and how you send it to your deconstruct function and the deconstruct function itself.

Comment: @CoreyLakey https://pastebin.com/1eaZDLKK Here is a pastebin of the code I am currently using (moved from the "flag" method to the "passing a ** to the deconstructor", not as elegant but it makes more sense, I think). The names of the types might be a bit different from the code here, as the given here was just an example and the one in the pastebin is from the actual project.
By the way, thank you for the help so far :)

Comment: @Meiogordo You are setting player ( which is not a pointer ) to a *Player which essentially sets the value of player to the address of the returned pointer. Nothing more. You understand pointers to pointers and `->` operator?

Comment: @CoreyLakey player, a member of the Robinix struct is, in fact, a Player *, so I don't believe there is a problem there, because the types match (otherwise there would be a compilation error, or at least warning, I think). Yes, I believe I understand those, I just want some input on the approach I am taking to deconstructing, i.e if setting the pointer to the object to NULL after deallocating is the best course of action to make sure that the pointer is not dereferenced wrongly

Comment: Because the pointer would be passed by copy if the destructor received a Player * instead of a Player **, we would be generating a sort of dangling reference, I believe because we could not set the Player * in the struct that was calling the function to NULL

Comment: @Meiogordo You are definately confusing yourself and me lol. " I believe because we could not set the Player * in the struct that was calling the function to NULL" What??? I am trying my best to follow here.

Comment: @CoreyLakey sorry for the confusion. I was calling the destructor of Player in the Robinix object, by passing its member, player, which is a Player *. It would be destroyed, but the Player * passed couldn't be set to NULL, since the Player * was passed by copy and thus doing player_ptr = NULL inside the destructor had no effect. I then resorted to the code I have sent above, in which the destructor receives a Player ** now so that the original Player * of the Robinix object can be set to NULL, indicating that the object was, in fact, destroyed.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with until now and the one I want input on, to understand if it is a decent idea, or if there is a better approach.

Comment: @Meiogordo. I think I see what you're asking. Quick question, after deleting player with `void destroy_player(Player ** p_ptr) ` without using `*p_ptr = NULL;` I would expect p_ptr to already be NULL because of the `free`. Is it not at that point? This would give me a hint as to what could be going on.

Comment: @CoreyLakey I do not believe that `free` sets a pointer to NULL, or does it? Since to do that it would have to modify the address that the pointer is pointing at (the pointer value), and thus it would have the same problem I have, and we would have to pass in a pointer to the pointer to the thing we want to `free`

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing this, then, to ask for input on what would be the best way to overcome this problem: …

What *would be the best way* is primarily opinion-based, but of the ways you listed the worst is the first, where one has to keep two variables (pointer and flag) synchronized.

> Any other solution…

Another solution would be using a macro, e. g.:

```
#define destroy_player(p) do { /* whatever cleanup needed */; free(p), p = NULL; } while (0)
…
    destroy_player(gi_ptr->player);
```